# How to calculate the average of a set of random numbers including additional conditions in C?

Tags: c, simulation, montecarlo

I'm trying to calculate the average of a set of random numbers (all of them between 0 and 1), considering if other conditions are fulfilled. That is, calculate the average of a list of random numbers for every value of a `float y` while it is less than 1. I also need to consider the number of iterations required to do it.

The following is the code I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define L 2
#define STEPS 10
#define ITERATIONS L*L

FILE *doc;

int main() {
    doc = fopen("document.txt", "w");
    float y = 0.0;
    float r;
    float sum_r = 0.0;
    float mean_r = 0.0;
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    fprintf(doc, "y    mean of r \n\n");

    while (y < 1) { 
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERATIONS; iter++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < STEPS; t++) {
                r = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
                printf("r=%f\n", r);
                sum_r += r;
            }
            mean_r = sum_r / (float)STEPS;
                
            fprintf(doc," %f          %f \n\n", y, mean_r);
        }   
        y = y + 0.01;
    }   
    fclose(doc);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I get averages above of 1, and it is incorrect. Also, I don't know exactly how to include the `ITERATIONS` since I get incorrect values for the average of those number every time.

Note:

What I need to obtain is something like

```
for y=0.00
   calculate the average of:
        0.3545
        0.5678
        0.2346
           .
           .
           .
        0.6786

for y=0.01
   calculate the average of:
        0.7893
        0.1234
        0.3899
           .
           .
           .
        0.8726

for y=0.02
           .
           .
           .
           .


and so on only while `y` is less than 1 and considering the number of iterations.
```

Comment: You have to reset sum_r to zero at the start of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple issues I can spot here.

Firstly in each loop (before the `for (int t = 0; t < STEPS; t++)` line, you'll need to reset `sum_r` to 0, otherwise you'll get means higher than 1.

Secondly, you'll find that y ends up larger than 1, because float arithmetic isn't perfectly precise. When you add 0.1 to y a bunch of times eventually it gets to 0.9999999 instead of 1. It would be a better idea to set y as an integer and iterate until y is 100, adding 1 each time. Then just divide y by 100 when you print.

There's a few other issues re: code style but that's better left for the code review forum.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I add 0.01 to y every time. I also have another question Is it correct the other loop regarding the number of iterations?

Comment: @base12masterrace: Welcome to SO! good answer. You might add that `#define ITERATIONS L*L` is risky and should be written `#define ITERATIONS  (L*L)`

Comment: @Auyk you can simply divide `y` by `100.0` whenever you need the original behaviour of `y` as a number between 0 and 1